# How to do batch updates?

Tags: kotlin, sql-update, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to update a specific column on a list of rows in MySql using Exposed.

Actually Exposed supports a `batchInsert`, but there is nothing similar to a `batchUpdate`, is there any workaround for this?

NOTE: the table is not an `IdTable`.

Comment: R u using Room?

Comment: nope, just kotlin with exposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are BatchUpdateStatement which works with IdTables.

```
val yourData = listOf<DataToUpdate>()
BatchUpdateStatement(FooTable).apply {
    yourData.forEach {
        addBatch(it.id)
        this[FooTable.name] = it.name
        this[FooTable.column] = it.field
    }
    execute(Transaction.current())
}
```

Comment: actually the table isn't an IdTable

Comment: Then it's impossible to make batch update because Exposed can't determine identity condition for each update.

Comment: any idea how do we add the where condition to this